# Data normalization in comparing sets of data in teechart - c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, teechart

Scenario:

I am using a teechart to display data.  These sets of data are absorption plots.  I am display multiple absorption plots at once.  Everything is fine until I use factors that are far apart from each other in value.  Basically, I am comparing the same plot but each one is factored different.  When I graph, for instance a set of data with a factor of 1, 3, 100, I have a hard time comparing these sets of data because the plots with a lower factor is hard to see because the plot with a higher factor "fills" the windows of the teechart.  I am trying to come up with a way to normalize this data so I can see all plots and compare them much easier. I am very new to teechart, so anything will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use multiple custom axes, one for each series so that they are automatically scaled accordingly with associated series values. For more information on custom axes please read tutorial 4 and check the *All Features\Welcome !\Axes* section in the features demo. Both tutorials and demo can be found at TeeChart's program group.